# SQL and Mongo Equivalent query

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, database

I have a table as UserData which has strucure like

```
 id category    value
 1  AR          100
 2  WT          90
 3  WT          12
 4  AR          1000
 5  AR          2005
 6  WT          122
 7  BP          112
 8  BP          18
```

now  I want to select all rows which has maximum  value in the indiviual category. so my result set should be.

```
id  category    value   
5   AR          2005    
6   WT          122     
7   BP          112
```

I want to have this in both MongoDB and SQL server query.

In SQL I tried this

```
     select id,category,value from
        (select id,
                category,
                value,
                max(value)
        over (partition by category) result
        from   UserData ) a 
       where a.result=a.value order by a.id
```

this is giving me desired result but somehow I feel that it is not good

so I want a better solution for this in SQL and corresponding equivalent solution for MongoDB

Comment: If your SQL works, you are not using MySQL.

Comment: yes I am using sql query in sql server management studio.

Comment: You should have asked **one** question for each format. The result otherwise ( and it's already happened ) is that it is likely you will receive answers that answers either one or the other, and not both.

Comment: sure.I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a mongo solution, but if you don't care about Id - here is the way to get the highest value for a category.

```
   SELECT   DISTINCT
            Category, MAX(Value)
   FROM     UserData
   GROUP BY category
```

Excuse me if this is more simplistic than what you desire.

Comment: You shouldn't need DISTINCT with GROUP BY.

Comment: You do when you have category and max in the same set. I tested in sql server management studio 2012.

Comment: I need to fetch Id also. Moreover we don`t need distinct here

Comment: If you require fetch id - I believe what you have is the best solution. Maybe some great mind will come along with something better, I have to agree that its not the most elegant way, but it works.